# Normalize.css and single-direction margins (margin-bottom)

Tags: css, margin, normalize

Could anybody share a modified **Normalize.css** file with margins declared as **single-directional** (i.e. *margin-bottom* only)?

Or is there an **actual** default style sheet such as [this one](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html), based on which I could modify the file myself?

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're after default stylesheets, you can find a repository of all browser/spec specific settings [here](https://github.com/sw4/revert.css)

The one you refer to is the W3C [recommended default style sheet](https://github.com/sw4/revert.css/blob/master/revert_w3chtml4.css)

Comment: Thank you for the link!

Looking through all the stylesheets would take a great amount of time, so that's why I'm asking if somebody has created the modified Normalize.css before.